# How can I swap two numbers by address?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int **a,int **b)
{
    int **k;
    k=a;
    a=b;
    b=k;
}
int main()
{
    int a=3,b=6,*x=&a,*y=&b;
    fun(&x,&y);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

I swap the address,why it still outputs 3 6.
So what's the correct way to swap the two address?

Comment: You swap the addresses of the ***local*** pointers in the `fun` function. But even if you use the *dereference* operator (which is what you're supposed to do) you will still get the wrong output, as you have a level of indirection to much.

Comment: As you can see in the two answers, your question is unclear. Please explain the deisred effect of "swap two numbers by address".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p = ...` never persists across the function call. Like everything else in C, if you want to change the caller's data, dereference the pointers you're given. `k` should be `int *`, and the assignments should be `int *k = *a; *a = *b; *b = k;`. that's it. Note also this changes *nothing* about the original `a` and `b`. All your swapping at this point are pointer values.

This code swaps two integers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int *a,int *b)
{
    int k = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = k;
}

int main()
{
    int a=3,b=6;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    fun(&a,&b);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3 6
6 3
```

Whereas, this code swaps two pointers. The integers they point to (a and b) remain as-is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int **a,int **b)
{
    int *k = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = k;
}

int main()
{
    int a=3,b=6,*x=&a,*y=&b;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    printf("%d %d\n",*x,*y); // note using x and y with deref
    fun(&x,&y);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    printf("%d %d\n",*x,*y); // note using x and y with deref
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3 6
3 6
3 6
6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it clear from the first expression .

```
int a=3,b=6,*x=&a,*y=&b;
```

Now breaking it down .

```
int a = 3, b = 6
```

[image: variable initialized]

Here `a` and `b` are two memory locations . Say `a` is `10000000` and `b` is `10010000`. So , after we write `a = 3 , b = 6` the value `3` takes the place in memory location `10000000` and `6` in `10010000` . Now ,

```
*x=&a,*y=&b;
```

[image: pointers points to variable]

means , `x` is an integer pointer that has the address of integer variable `a` which is `10000000` and `y` has the address of `b` which is `10010000` . Note that , both `x` and `y` are also variable which can store the address as value of any integer variable . `x` and `y` has  locations in memory let say `11000000` and `11011111`. Now ,

```
fun(&x,&y);
```

[image: function called]

You are passing the address of `x` and `y` to the function `fun` . It looks like `fun(11000000, 11010000)` .
Note that , you are not passing the address of `a` and `b` ! In function `fun` these addresses are in `a` ( `pa` for clarity ) and `b` (`pb` for clarity),

```
void fun(int **a,int **b)
{
    int **k;
    k = a;
    a = b;
    b = k;
}
```

[image: pointers swapped]

Here , `a`(`pa`), `b`(`pb`) and `k` are pointers of pointer . They can hold the address of an integer pointer .`a`(`pa`) and `b`(`pb`) are holding the address of `x` and `y` respectively . Now when you swapping `a`(`pa`) and `b`(`pb`) you actually swapping the addresses ( of x and y ) in `a`(`pa`) and `b`(`pb`). So , after the function `fun` finishes it's execution `a` (`pa`) is pointing `y` and `b`(`pb`) is pointing `x` . In main function , nothing actually happened . When you do the following ,

```
void fun(int **a, int **b)
{
    int *k;
    k=*a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = k;
}
```

it swaps the address in `x` and `y` and they now pointing to `b` and `a`(in main function).
[image: x and y swaps]

Now the final version comes ! If you would do the following , it actually make you happy ,

```
void fun(int **a, int **b)
{
    int k;
    k=**a;
    **a = **b;
    **b = k;
}
```

[image]

I hope you understand it . Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Try this to swap the values to which *a and *b of fun() points

```
void fun(int **a, int **b)
{
int k;
k = **a;
**a = **b;
**b = k;
}
```

Comment: "swap by address" could mean "swap the addresses" or "swap the values referenced by the referenced addresses".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
int **k;
k=a;
a=b;
b=k;
```

you should have tried this:

```
int *k;
k=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=k;
```

And yeah, you should print `*x` and `*y`, because those are the variables you swap, not `a` and `b`.

Comment: Still it doesn't swap the values as pointed by @Some programmer dude in the comments

Comment: He wants to print a and b as 6 and 3

Comment: "swap by address" could mean "swap the addresses" or "swap the values referenced by the referenced addresses".